# Start SpringBoot server despite database down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have this SpringBoot app that connects to a PostgreSQL database. I'd like to start the server even if database is down, but `continue-on-error=true` doesn't work. When I simulate database down (wrong password) I get the `Error creating bean with name 'countryRepository'` error, even though the repositories are loaded lazily.

**I think it's because of default @EnableJpaRepositories. Does anyone know how to ititialize it lazily as well?**

SOLVED by adding custom, lazily initialized implementations of EntityManagerFactory, EntityManager, TransactionManager, TransactionTemplate

application.properties

```
# Database Properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/world-db
spring.datasource.username=world
spring.datasource.password=world123F
spring.datasource.hikari.initializationFailTimeout=0

# Not working... 
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=0
spring.datasource.hikari.initialization-fail-timeout=-1

# Hibernate Properties
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Lazy
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.flairstech.workshop")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public CountryLanguage getCountryLanguage(){
        return new CountryLanguage();
    }

    @Bean
    public Country getCountry(){
        return new Country();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
 and check

Comment: Doesn't help...

Comment: The issue might be with the spring version that you are using.

Comment: 2.3.1.RELEASE, why?

Comment: Because of continue-on-error=true does not work with every version of spring. Now add *spring.datasource.driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver* also and checks again

Comment: I've added lines in application.properties that I've tried and doesn't work